# Optimization of the Oracle function

Tags: oracle, performance, function, optimization, plsql

I have following function which replaces the keywords from lookup table. This function is working fine as per functionality but taking lot of time for execution. I need a help to rewrite this function to optimize.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_keyword (p_in_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS
 l_name   VARCHAR2 (4000);
 l_keyword_found BOOLEAN;

 CURSOR curSpl IS
  SELECT *
    FROM RSRV_KEY_LKUPS
   WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
   AND upper(POSITION) = 'SPECIAL';

  CURSOR curAll IS
  SELECT *
    FROM RSRV_KEY_LKUPS
   WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
   AND upper(POSITION) = 'ALL';

  CURSOR c IS
  SELECT *
    FROM RSRV_KEY_LKUPS
   WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'
   AND upper(POSITION)  in ('LEADING', 'TRAILING'); 

 BEGIN
 --Rule 6:Remove the leading and trailing blank spaces
 l_name := TRIM (UPPER (p_in_name)); 

 --Rule 0:Remove all the special keyword --C/O
    FOR recSpl in curSpl LOOP
        IF (regexp_instr(l_name, '(^|\s)'||recSpl.KEY_WORD ||'(\s|$)') > 0) THEN
            l_name := regexp_replace(l_name,'(^|\s)'||recSpl.KEY_WORD ||'(\s|$)', ' '); 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
 --Rule 1: replace punctuation with single space
   l_name := regexp_replace(l_name, '[[:punct:]]',' '); 
 --Rule 5:Remove multiple spaces in a word and replace with single blank space
   l_name := REGEXP_REPLACE (l_name, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' '); 
 --Rule 6:Remove the leading and trailing blank spaces
   l_name := TRIM (l_name); 

 --Rule 2: replace "THE" and "AND" with a blank space anywhere in the field

   FOR recAll in curAll LOOP
        IF (regexp_instr(l_name, '(^|\s)'||recAll.KEY_WORD ||'(\s|$)') > 0) THEN
            l_name := regexp_replace(l_name,'(^|\s)'||recAll.KEY_WORD ||'(\s|$)', ' '); 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
 --Rule 5:Remove multiple spaces in a word and replace with single blank space
   l_name := REGEXP_REPLACE (l_name, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' '); 
 --Rule 6:Remove the leading and trailing blank spaces
   l_name := TRIM (l_name); 
 --Rule 3 remove LEADING keywords
   l_keyword_found := false;
   for rec in c LOOP
        IF     UPPER (rec.POSITION) = 'LEADING'
         AND SUBSTR(l_name, 1,INSTR(l_name,' ',1) - 1) = rec.key_word --INSTR (UPPER (l_name)|| ' ', UPPER (rec.KEY_WORD || ' '), 1) > 0
         AND l_keyword_found = false
        THEN 
            l_name := SUBSTR(l_name,INSTR(l_name,' ',1)+1);--l_name := LTRIM(l_name, rec.key_word);
            l_keyword_found := true;
        END IF;
        EXIT  WHEN (l_keyword_found);
   END LOOP;

 --Rule 5:Remove multiple spaces in a word and replace with single blank space
   l_name := REGEXP_REPLACE (l_name, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' '); 
 --Rule 6:Remove the leading and trailing blank spaces
   l_name := TRIM (l_name);  

 --Rule 4 remove TRAILING keywords
   l_keyword_found := false;
   for rec in c LOOP
        IF     UPPER (rec.POSITION) = 'TRAILING'
         AND SUBSTR(l_name, INSTR(l_name,' ',-1) + 1) = rec.key_word
         AND l_keyword_found = false
        THEN 
            l_name := SUBSTR(l_name,1,INSTR(l_name,' ',-1)-1);  --l_name := RTRIM(l_name, rec.key_word);
            l_keyword_found := true;
        END IF;
        EXIT  WHEN (l_keyword_found);
   END LOOP;
 --Rule 5:Remove multiple spaces in a word and replace with single blank space
   l_name := REGEXP_REPLACE (l_name, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' '); 
 --Rule 6:Remove the leading and trailing blank spaces
   l_name := TRIM (l_name); 
   return l_name;
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      raise_application_error (
         -20001,
         'An error was encountered - ' || SQLCODE || ' -ERROR- ' || SQLERRM);
 END;
/
```

This function removes LEADING and TRAILING keywords only from first and last positions respectively and SPECIAL and ALL keywords from everywhere in input string. Sample Input 1

```
MR MRS THE Jones AND PVT COMPANY
```

Output

```
MRS JONES PVT
```

Sample Input 2

```
MR MRS Doe PVT COMPANY LTD
```

Output

```
MRS DOE PVT
```

Lookup table have data like below:

```
SPECIAL - C/O
ALL - AND, THE
LEADING - MR, MRS, DR
TRAILING - COMPANY, PVT, LIMITED
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Comment: You probably have a lot of context switches happening (changing from database to pl/sql). This can be changed for example by trying to do everything within database (this could prove a challenge with all these string operations) or at least trying to reduce the number and use of cursors.

Comment: you could also try the Native Compile Mode: http://www.confio.com/logicalread/oracle-11g-native-compilation-mc02/#.VA2i3WccRaQ maybe this will help to reduce the CPU-Time for executing all the PL/SQL Code.

Comment: Instead of looping through every row in RSRV_KEY_LKUPS three times for position = 'SPECIAL', 'ALL' and 'LEADING'/'TRAILING' and applying row-by-row regex checks in a loop, I would try to (1) do it all in a single pass (or as few passes as possible), and (2) perform the substitution in the cursor. As a first step, can you at least parameterise those cursors so the result sets are limited to rows matching l_name, instead of getting everything and stepping through it in a loop?